# How do you save the state of the detail view in a master-detail ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a master detail application and for each cell in the master view, I want a unique detail view. I figured what I could do was save the state of the detailed view when exiting the view and then when a different cell is selected somehow access the saved data for that view and display it on the detail view. The only type of objects on the detail view are textviews and image views. How would I go about doing this? Is there a better way?

Comment: There's not enough information about your models. Where are you getting information for your detail view?

Comment: I'm using the default master detail template in xcode. I have a master view and a detail view each with a viewcontroller

Comment: I meant, for each of your detail views, where are you getting the information from to fill your detail views? Or do your detail views have blank/default information in them?

Comment: I have a single imageview and then i add multiple textviews. I want my app to be able to remember the state of the detailed view depending on which cell in the master view is selected.

Comment: The detailviewcontroller controls the textsview added and what is displayed on the image view

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a very advanced programmer. I'll try to give as much info as I can.

Comment: In general, you don't save the state of the view. You save the state of your model, which would be reflected in your view. There are of course exceptions but without knowing more about your app structure it is hard to say what the right course of action is.

Comment: how would I control the state of the model?

Comment: It depends entirely on how your program is set up.

Answer (score 1):

If the master detail view is like a settings page then you could save that data in `NSUserDefaults`

=> To set value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue: @"some_value" forKey: @"some_setting"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

=> To retrieve value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.label1.text = [defaults stringForKey: @"some_setting"];
```

---

You could use a `Model` like following:

```
Model - A common class that remembers all the settings/configurations
Master VC - Do some changes and store those changes in the Model
Detail VC - Access the Model and display cells accordingly
```

Comment: Could that be used for an image view? also the number of textviews and number of different cells in the master view is infinite, so how would i make a key for each if i didnt know the amount there were?

Comment: If you have infinite cells then like @sosborn suggested, it is better to use a model to store that information. I have updated my answer to give you a basic idea of how to implement a `Model`

Comment: How do you use a model? I've never done anything like that before

Comment: Its a simple class to store and retrieve data

Comment: Have a look at http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/08/13/design-patterns-model-view-controller/ and search about MVC's model's examples

Comment: You could use core data or simply one .h and .m file where you store all you variables, access them and update them. Check which would be a better option for you and use that.

Comment: I would think core data would be the better option since I don't know how many variables I need to save. It could be infinite.